# Matplotlib cmap colours are not in the same order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting two dataframes on the same plot, together with the means of each dataset with the same cmap each dataset. However, the order of the colours in which the cmap is applied to the different datasets is different. Can someone point our what I am doing wrong, please?

Here is the output. As you can see, the markers have the same shape, but different colours (the x):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#reading
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,20,size=(7, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(30,40,size=(7, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))

#plot the first DataFrame
#trying to select the first 8 RGBA codes from viridis - does not wo
ax = df1.plot(style = ['.','*','1','2','3','4','+','x'],figsize=(8,4),cmap = 'Accent')
#ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler(color = cmap.colors[0:7]))
ax = df1.mean(axis=1).plot(c='red',style = '--',label = 'M1 mean')

#plot the second dataframe
ax = df2.mean(axis=1).plot(ax=ax,c='black',style = '--',label = 'M3 mean')
ax = df2.plot(ax=ax,style = ['.','*','1','2','3','4','+','x'],cmap = 'Accent')

#fiddle with the axes
plt.ylim(0,40)
plt.xlim(-0.5,6.2)

#add the labels

plt.ylabel('Average Efficiency')

#make sure all the ticks are visible
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,7),np.arange(0,7))
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'])
#change the legend
plt.legend([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,'M1_mean','M3 mean'],title = 'Groups',bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.1)

#increase the font
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 10}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
plt.show()
print('done')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something strange is happening, probably some kind of bug in how pandas works with matplotlib: whenever a marker is a lower case letter, it doesn't seem to obey to the given colormap, it just follows the 'prop_cycle'.

Here are two workarounds. The simplest is just to avoid all these lower case letter [markers](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) and choose different ones.

Another workaround, is to explicitly set a color cycle, and reset it when the second part is plotted. Note that `cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis', 9)` selects 9 equally spaced colors from the viridis colormap. If no explicit number is set, viridis has 256 colors, of which the 8 first all are very similar (dark purple). We choose 9 colors and later ignore the last one, because the yellow has too little contrast for this application. (Don't forget to leave out the `cmap` argument from pandas `plot`).

An explicit color cycle gives more control over exactly which colors are used. You can also choose e.g. [`cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Dark2')`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) which only has darker colors with sufficient contrast towards the white background.

Here is some code to demonstrate how it could work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 25, size=(7, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(30, 45, size=(7, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))

# create a color map with 9 colors from viridis
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis', 9)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
markers = ['.', '*', '1', '2', '3', '4', '+', 'x']
# plot the first dataframe
# set the prop_cycle to use 8 colors from the given colormap
ax.set_prop_cycle(color=cmap.colors[0:8])
df1.plot(style=markers, ax=ax)
df1.mean(axis=1).plot(c='red', style='--', label='M1 mean', ax=ax)

# plot the second dataframe
ax.set_prop_cycle(color=cmap.colors[0:8])
df2.plot(ax=ax, style=markers)
df2.mean(axis=1).plot(ax=ax, c='black', style='--', label='M3 mean')

plt.ylim(0, 45)
plt.xlim(-0.5, 6.2)
plt.ylabel('Average Efficiency')
plt.xticks(range(7), ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'])
# change the legend
plt.legend(title='Groups', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.1, ncol=2)

font = {'family': 'normal',
        'weight': 'normal',
        'size': 10}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you, this works! I also tried the cycle version but somehow did not manage to get it done. Nice ! One last thing: I would like to have the groups only once in the legend , and the M1 and M3 means. Can I supress the second time the Groups appear, and keep only the M3 mean?

Comment: Nevermind - the version I had posted already took care of this, and changing the one marker did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, your legend version is very fine. I just changed it in the my test code to better see what was happening.